# Apache rewrite rule to remove part of a URL from a Silex route

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, silex

I'm trying to create an Apache rewrite rule that would remove part of a URL for a Silex Application. I want to keep only one virtual host in Apache, so using a virtual host is not a solution. The DocumentRoot in Apache is **/var/www/** , and the Silex index.php is in **/var/www/ROR_V2/web/**

What I want is to have this URL : **http://my-site.org/ROR_V2/user/login**

Point to this route in my Silex App : **/user/login**

I have tried, I have failed, I don't get it.

My Apache conf file (I'm not using .htaccess) looks like this :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www

<Directory /var/www/ROR_V2>
    Options -Indexes
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /web
    LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ROR_V2/(.*) $1
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```

And I get a

*The requested URL /web/index.php was not found on this server.*

Other answers found here and there have not helped, so I decided to ask the question here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit : So what I ended up doing is to hardcode the URL within the Silex routes, making it a configuration parameter in the form : `$app['BASE_URL']='ROR_V2'`
when I'm on my prod server and 
`$app['BASE_URL']=''`
... when I'm testing.
This is, of course, ugly and unsatisfactory and should really belong in the web server configuration...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the purpose of your needs (why do you use Silex just to log a user?) but if you want that `http://my-site.org/ROR_V2/user/login` points on `/var/www/ROR_V2/web` and all other URI were based on `/var/www/ROR_V2` you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/ROR/user/login
RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [QSA,L]
```

And I remove the `RewriteBase /web`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "/user/login" is just one route among many, meant as an example. The bottom line is : I want to write my Silex app with "/" as root (not /ROR_V2), yet have visitors type the my-site.org/ROR_V2/user/login URL, all this in my-site.org Virtual host